# Read and split line by line in text file

Tags: vb.net, foreach, reader

I am trying to read a text file from my applications resources. For each line in this text file I want to split the text before and after the comma.

Each line in txt file looks like this:

```
-125.325235,4845636
```

My issue is that the function loops and does not end constantly repeating the for each statement

```
For Each Line As String In My.Resources.CompanyBases
    MsgBox(My.Resources.CompanyBases.Split(","c).First)
    MsgBox(My.Resources.CompanyBases.Split(","c).Last)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't ever get a resource over and over like that. Those properties are not "live". Every time you get the property, the resource has to be extracted from your assembly. If you need to use the value multiple times, get the property once and assign it to a variable, then use that variable over and over.

Secondly, you're not getting a file. The whole point of resources is that they are not distinct files but rather data compiled into your assembly. It's just a `String` like any other. How would you usually split a `String` on line breaks?

Finally, you have a `For Each` loop with a loop control variable `Line`, yet you never use that variable inside the loop. It should be `Line` that you're splitting inside the loop, not the resource property containing all the lines.

```vb
For Each line In My.Resources.CompanyBases.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Dim fields = line.Split(","c)

    Debug.WriteLine(fields(0))
    Debug.WriteLine(fields(1))
Next
```

Note that, if you're using .NET Core, `Split` will accept a `String` as well as a `String` array.